# In singular value decomposition, is there a difference between starting with transpose(A) * A or A * transpose(A)?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, svd, singular-values

When calculating the SVD for a matrix I go through these steps :

1/ Calculate tranpose(A)*A

2/ Find the eigenvalues for that matrix and deduce $\Sigma$

3/ Find the eigenvectors and deduce $V$

4/ Deduce $U$ from the relation $AV=U \Sigma$

Now suppose I started with A*transpose(A), what does change in these steps? Will I be calculating the eigenvalues of $U$ instead of $V$?

Comment: Try applying the exact same steps to $A^\top$. Note that if $A = U \Sigma V^\top$ is an SVD, then so is $A^\top = V \Sigma^\top U^\top$

Comment: @BenGrossmann so the matrix of eigenvectors in step 3 are those of $U^T$? and not $V$?

Comment: The eigenvectors of $AA^\top$ are the columns of $U$, and then one can get $V$ from $U$ using the relation from step 4, which can be rewritten as
$$
A^\top U = V \Sigma^\top.
$$